# Why does the 1D difference not start from 0%?

Tags: price, chart

I'm trying to understand %change in price charts on Morningstar.

Here is a %change in price for 2 securities in the last 1D.

[image]

Why is it that neither of them started from zero? What's going on here? Does the negative start have to do with after-hours trading? Is it just a bug? Or is there some other explanation?

You can view the chart [here](http://quotes.morningstar.com/chart/etf/chart.action?t=SPY&region=usa&culture=en_US&dataParams=%7B%22zoomKey%22%3A1%2C%22version%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22showNav%22%3Atrue%2C%22mainSettingId%22%3A%22main%22%2C%22navSettingId%22%3A%22nav%22%2C%22benchmarkSettingId%22%3A%22benchmark%22%2C%22sliderBgSettingId%22%3A%22sliderBg%22%2C%22volumeSettingId%22%3A%22volume%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22FEUSA00001%7C0P000001F6%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22FE%7CST%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22USA%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22ARCX%3ASPY%7CXNYS%3ACMP%22%2C%22qsType%22%3A%22USA%3ASPY%7C0P000001F6%22%2C%22baseCurrency%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22defaultBenchmarks%22%3A%5B%22%24FOCA%24LB%24%24%7CLarge%20Blend%7CCA%5DFE%22%2C%22XIUSA04G92%7CS%26P%20500%20TR%20USD%7CXI%22%5D%2C%22hideDividendMenu%22%3Afalse%2C%22startDay%22%3A%2206%2F18%2F2019%22%2C%22endDay%22%3A%2206%2F18%2F2019%22%2C%22chartWidth%22%3A955%7D). It's free.

Comment: I've wondered about that too. Maybe the `0%` is yesterday's ending price, and the immediate morning bids on these securities were different from yesterday's ending prices.

Comment: That's a good hypothesis. But it doesn't seem to be what they're doing. E.g. CMP closed at 56.28 yesterday. But the 1D graphs starts from 56.73, which is *above* 56.28, but the graph still starts from -0.68%, which is *below* 0%.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original chart or is it a premium service to see it?

Comment: It's free to see it. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Curse you, Facts, for foiling me again!!

Comment: Re CMP, I think it might be  bad data from the provider.  The first 4 trades during regular hours were at 9:31:00 EST at $56.84, $56.84, $56.73 and $56.73.  The graph should start at $56.84 but since at four trades were nearly simultaneous, they grabbed $56.73.  GIGO?

Comment: That provides some light, but it still doesn't explain the -0.68%. The value that 56.73 is lower than by -0.68% is 57.12, which is neither yesterday's close value nor one of the other three opening values that you listed.

Comment: If you click on the one year (or longer) icon, it resets the beginning of the graphs to zero and the % change graph is continuous from that date through  today.  That implies that  the daily % is based off of the beginning price rather than the previous day  but I'm only guessing.   I can't make the numbers add up.  Perhaps an exploration of a Morningstar Help Index (if it exists?) or contacting them for an explanation?

Comment: I will contact their support and update with their response.

Comment: @BobBaerker Morningstar has confirmed that it's a change from the after-hours price before trading opened. Thanks a lot to you and RonJohn for investigating this. It was very interesting to me.

Comment: Their answer makes no sense to me.  Data services report closing prices (not after hours) so daily ROC is calculated on a close to close basis.  Take ADBE.  It's up $10.30, all of which occurred during after hours last night.  Yet the Morningstar graph depicts none of this.  I fail to see what use their % graphs offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of before and after hours trading. The 0% represents where the stock closed the night before. Since the stock market technically isn't open overnight, the change is "instant" at the open of the market.

Comment: I suspected this. Do you have any data about the before-hours trading to verify this, so that I can accept this answer?

Comment: @Zesty  What makes you think that trade will start at previous day price?  Imagine this is a  "previous hour" change tracking.

Comment: Your answer has been confirmed by Morningstar.

Comment: This answer  doesn't explain the graph that the OP put up.  Posting  actual prices that support the numbers in the graph would.

Answer (score 2):

In the image you show, it looks like both graphs *end* precisely at 0%, which is unlikely to be a coincidence. Both of them must be showing prices *relative to the price **now***.

This has the practical advantage that if you change to the 5D view, the end of the chart will show the two graphs in the same relative prosition as the 1D view does.